# Alter materialized view in BigQuery results in "Unexpected statement"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am getting an error "`Unexpected statement type ALTER_MATERIALIZED_VIEW`" when following [this guide here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/materialized-views#alter).  How do I alter a materialized view using the DDL?

Comment: What command are you specifically issuing and what is the error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Unexpected statement type ALTER_MATERIALIZED_VIEW` is actually a warning message, not an error. This is the current message prompt but, it has been brought up to Google Cloud for a fix since the message should not be a warning message but a confirmation message.

Executing the command:

> ALTER MATERIALIZED VIEW project-id.my_dataset.my_mv_table
>
> SET OPTIONS (enable_refresh=true)

This currently shows the warning message `Unexpected statement type ALTER_MATERIALIZED_VIEW`. I simulated this in my project and see how it goes.

With my replication, I was to update a materialized view using the same command you found in this [article](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/materialized-views#alter). I used the parameters `enable_refresh=false, description="Refresh update to FALSE"` for testing purposes. See initial details of the materialized view below.

[image]

After executing the command, here's what showed as the prompt.

[image]

While the warning message prompt showed, the details I updated in the materialized view were correct. Here is a screenshot of the details of the materialized view after the update.

[image]

Thus, you are following the correct article in updating your materialized view.